Juego de barajas python
    import random
from tkinter import messagebox
print("En caso de no tener carta alguna escribe el numero 100 y conseguirás una carta")

class Carta():
    def __init__(self, palo, numero):
        self.palo = palo
        self.numero = numero

class Baraja():
    def __init__(self):
        self.baraja = []
        self.crear_baraja()


    def crear_baraja(self):
        self.palos = ["Diamantes", "picas", "corazones", "treboles"]
        self.num = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10,11,12]
        for p in self.palos:
            
            for n in self.num:
                self.carta = p,n
                self.baraja.append(self.carta)
        random.shuffle(self.baraja)
    def eliminar_carta(self,posicion):
        carta = self.baraja.pop(posicion)
        
        return carta
        
    def enseñar_baraja(self):
        print(self.baraja)
    def baraja(self):
        return self.baraja
    def largo(self):
        return len(self.baraja)
        


class Jugador():
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        self.mano = []
        self.nombre = nombre
        
    def añadir(self,carta):
        if carta != 100:
            self.mano.append(carta)
    def enseñar(self):
        print(f"Cartas {self.nombre}")
        con = 0
        for c in self.mano:
            print(con, c)
            con += 1
    def echar_carta(self):
        posicion = int(input(f"¿En que posción se encuentra la carta que quieres echar {self.nombre}?"))
        if posicion == 100:
            return 100
            pass
            
        c = self.mano[posicion]
        return c
        del c
    def mano(self):
        return self.mano
    def largo_mano(self):
        return len(self.mano)
    
    

class Juego():
    def __init__(self):
        self.baraja_vacía = "no"
        self.baraja = Baraja()
        self.mesa = []
        self.j1 = Jugador("j1")
        self.contrincante = Jugador("Enemigo")
        self.jugar()
        self.ganador = "nadie"
        
        
        
    def añadir_a_mesa(self, carta, jugador):
        if str(carta) != "100":
        
            self.mesa.append(carta[1])
            self.mesa.append(jugador)
        else:
            pass
        print(self.mesa)
    def borrar_mesa(self):
        self.messa.clear()
    def jugar(self):
        no_carta = False
        self.detectar = "si"
        
        print("cartas j1")
        for x in range(0,10):
             
             c = self.baraja.eliminar_carta(x)
             self.j1.añadir(c)
       
        
        self.j1.enseñar()
        print("Cartas contrincante")
        for x in range(0,10):
             
             c = self.baraja.eliminar_carta(x)
             self.contrincante.añadir(c)
        
        
        self.contrincante.enseñar()

        #Caso de turno j1

        e = random.randint(0,2)
        if e == 1:
        
            c = self.j1.echar_carta()
            self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "j1")
                
            c1 = self.contrincante.echar_carta()
            print(c1)
            self.añadir_a_mesa(c,"j1")

            #Detección de ninguna carta
            while c1 == 100:
                print("Pasando")
                if self.baraja.largo() == 0:
                    print("La baraja está vacía")
                    self.baraja_vacía == "sí"
                    self.detectar == "no"

                    
                   
                    
                if c1 != 100:
                    
                        self.añadir_a_mesa(c1, "contrincante")
                        
                elif c1 == 100 and self.baraja_vacía == "no":
                        print("Aquí va una carta")
                        self.mesa.clear()
                        self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "j1")
                        self.contrincante.añadir(c1)
                        self.contrincante.añadir(self.baraja.eliminar_carta(0))
                        self.contrincante.enseñar()
                        c1 = self.contrincante.echar_carta()
                no_carta == True
                        
                    
               
                print(self.mesa)
                print(self.mesa[0])
                #Detección de si la carta es menor que la que echó el rival
                while self.mesa[2] < self.mesa[0] and self.detectar == "si" and no_carta == False:
                    
                    print("Ese número es menor que el del rival")
                    self.mesa.clear()
                    self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "j1")
                    self.contrincante.añadir(c1)
                    c1 = self.contrincante.echar_carta()
                    self.añadir_a_mesa(c1, "contrincante")
                self.ganador = "contrincante"
        #Caso rival
        else:
            
            c = self.contrincante.echar_carta()
            self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "contrincante")
                
            c1 = self.j1.echar_carta()
            print(c1)
            self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "j1")

            #Detección de ninguna carta
            while c1 == 100:
               print("Pasando")
               if self.baraja.largo() == 0:
                    print("La baraja está vacía")
                    self.baraja_vacía = "sí"
                    self.detectar = "no"

               
               if c1 != 100:
                    
                        self.añadir_a_mesa(c1, "j1")
               elif c1 == 100 and self.baraja_vacía == "no":
                        print("Aquí va una carta")
                        self.mesa.clear()
                        self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "contrincante")
                        self.j1.añadir(c1)
                        self.j1.añadir(self.baraja.eliminar_carta(0))
                        self.j1.enseñar()
                        c1 = self.j1.echar_carta()

                        no_carta = True
               while self.mesa[2] < self.mesa[0] and no_carta == False and self.detectar == "si":
                        
                        
                        print("Ese número es menor que el del rival")
                        self.mesa.clear()
                        self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "contrincante")
                        self.j1.añadir(c1)
                        c1 = self.j1.echar_carta()
                        self.añadir_a_mesa(c1, "j1")
                        self.ganador = "j1"
                        
                    
               
               print(self.mesa)
               #Detección de si la carta es menor que la que echó el rival

            while self.mesa[2] < self.mesa[0] and no_carta == False and self.detectar == "si":
                        
                        print("Ese número es menor que el del rival")
                        self.mesa.clear()
                        self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "contrincante")
                        self.j1.añadir(c1)
                        c1 = self.j1.echar_carta()
                        self.añadir_a_mesa(c1, "j1")
            self.ganador = "j1"

            while True:
                self.ronda()
    def ronda(self):
            no_carta = False
            if self.ganador == "j1":
                print("J1 ha ganado ahora le toca a el echar carta")
                self.j1.enseñar()
                self.contrincante.enseñar()
                c = self.j1.echar_carta()
                self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "j1")
                    
                c1 = self.contrincante.echar_carta()
                print(c1)
                self.añadir_a_mesa(c,"j1")

                #Caso de turno j1



                #Detección de ninguna carta
                while c1 == 100:
                    print("Pasando")
                    if self.baraja.largo() == 0:
                        print("La baraja está vacía")
                        self.baraja_vacía == "sí"
                        self.detectar == "no"
                    
                    if self.baraja_vacía != "sí":
                            
                            print("Aquí va una carta")
                            self.mesa.clear()
                            self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "j1")
                            self.contrincante.añadir(self.baraja.eliminar_carta(0))
                            self.contrincante.enseñar()
                            c1 = self.contrincante.echar_carta()
                        
                    if c1 != 100:
                        
                            self.añadir_a_mesa(c1, "contrincante")
                            
                    elif c1 == 100:
                            print("Aquí va una carta")
                            self.mesa.clear()
                            self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "j1")
                            self.contrincante.añadir(c1)
                            self.contrincante.añadir(self.baraja.eliminar_carta(0))
                            self.contrincante.enseñar()
                            c1 = self.contrincante.echar_carta()
                            self.ganador = "contrincante"
                    no_carta == True
                        
                            
                        
                   
                    print(self.mesa)
                    print(self.mesa[0])
                    #Detección de si la carta es menor que la que echó el rival
                while self.mesa[2] < self.mesa[0] and self.detectar == "si" and no_carta == False:
                        
                        print("Ese número es menor que el del rival")
                        self.mesa.clear()
                        self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "j1")
                        self.contrincante.añadir(c1)
                        c1 = self.contrincante.echar_carta()
                        self.añadir_a_mesa(c1, "contrincante")
                        self.ganador = "contrincante"
        #Caso rival
            else:
                print("El contrincante ha ganado le toca echar carta")
                self.j1.enseñar()
                self.contrincante.enseñar()
            
                c = self.contrincante.echar_carta()
                self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "contrincante")
                    
                c1 = self.j1.echar_carta()
                print(c1)
                self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "j1")

                #Detección de ninguna carta
                while c1 == 100:
                   print("Pasando")
                   if self.baraja.largo() == 0:
                        print("La baraja está vacía")
                        self.baraja_vacía = "sí"
                        self.detectar = "no"

                   if self.baraja_vacía != "sí":
                            print("Aquí va una carta")
                            self.mesa.clear()
                            self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "contrincante")
                            self.j1.añadir(self.baraja.eliminar_carta(0))
                            self.j1.enseñar()
                            c1 = self.j1.echar_carta()
                   if c1 != 100:
                        
                            self.añadir_a_mesa(c1, "j1")
                   elif c1 == 100:
                            print("Aquí va una carta")
                            self.mesa.clear()
                            self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "contrincante")
                            self.j1.añadir(c1)
                            self.j1.añadir(self.baraja.eliminar_carta(0))
                            self.j1.enseñar()
                            c1 = self.j1.echar_carta()
                   no_carta = True
                            
                        
                   
                   print(self.mesa)
                   #Detección de si la carta es menor que la que echó el rival

                while self.mesa[2] < self.mesa[0] and no_carta == False and self.detectar == "si":
                            
                            print("Ese número es menor que el del rival")
                            self.mesa.clear()
                            self.añadir_a_mesa(c, "contrincante")
                            self.j1.añadir(c1)
                            c1 = self.j1.echar_carta()
                            self.añadir_a_mesa(c1, "j1")
                self.ganador = "j1"
            self.comprobar()
    def comprobar(self):
        if self.j1.largo_mano() == 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("Ganador", "El jugador j1 ha ganado")
        elif self.contrincante.largo_mano() == 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("Ganador", "El contrincante ha ganado")
        

juego = Juego()

sé que soy una persona muy desordenada a la hora de programar pero ese no es el caso ahora, si alguien logra entender todo lo que pasa y lo resuelve me salvaría la vida, el problema es el siguiente, a la hora de escribir 100 por segunda vez en la ronda 1 me da un mensaje de error diciendo que list index out of range: while self.mesa[2] < self.mesa[0] and self.detectar == "si" and no_carta == False:
eso o algo parecido, si alguien me pudiese decir porque eso falla, llevo rayado así medio mes así que si alguien me ayudase

Hola responder123, cuando uno programa en solitario, puede hacer lo que quiera, cuando trabaja en equipo no, ahora somos un equipo, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y escribas bien tu código, así evitarás recibir votos negativos, y/o el cierre de la misma, En tu lugar, yo empezaría por refactorizar, por ejemplo, varias veces tienes, #Detección de ninguna carta, sacalo en una función aparte y usa un booleano, así con todo.

los metodo jugar y  ronda, son demasiado largos, refactorizarrrrr!!.

He revisado el código y no tengo la respuesta a tu pregunta. Lo mejor es reformular el modelo para simplificar la lógica, además de "pythonizar" el código.
Es un juego de cartas, y para este caso basta con representarlas con Letra+Número. Entonces, "D4" sería el 4 de Diamantes. No es necesario una clase.
Una mano, baraja y mesa son todas listas de cartas. Sólo necesito una clase para manejar los tres elementos:
class Mano:
    #   Mano es una lista de cero o más cartas.
    def __init__(self):
        self.mano = []

    def extraer(self):
        #   Extrae la primera carta de la baraja
        return self.mano.pop(0)

    def append(self, carta):
        #   Agregar una carta (no validamos que este repetida)
        self.mano.append(carta)

    def remove(self, carta):
        #  Remover una carta. No validamos que exista.
        self.mano.remove(carta)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join(carta for carta in self.mano)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.mano)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        # Implementa mano[item]
        return self.mano[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        # Implementa mano[key] = value
        self.mano[key] = value

Los métodos como __len__(), __getitem()__  se conocen como métodos mágicos o métodos dunder. Puedes leer sobre eso aquí.
Con está clase puedo crear una baraja:
#   Una baraja es una Mano con todas las cartas
baraja = Mano()
for palo in "DPCT":
    for numero in range(1, 13):
        baraja.append(f"{palo}{numero}")
random.shuffle(baraja)

Un jugador también es una mano, que parte vacía y a la cual le agregamos cartas extraidas de la baraja:
# Repartamos cinco cartas al jugador 1

player1 = Mano()
for i in range(5):
    player1.append(baraja.extraer()) #   Sacamos la primera carta de la baraja

La mesa tiene cartas y está inicialmente vacía:
#   La mesa también es una colección de cartas
mesa = Mano()

Hagamos una versión primitiva del juego, donde el jugador selecciona su carta por nombre ("C5", por ejemplo), sacandola de su mano y poniendola en la mesa.
#   Player1 selecciona una carta al azar y la juega
carta = input("Selecciona su carta: ").upper()
player1.remove(carta)
mesa.append(carta)

Código completo
import random


class Mano:
    #   Mano es una lista de cero o más cartas.
    def __init__(self):
        self.mano = []

    def extraer(self):
        #   Extrae la primera carta de la baraja
        return self.mano.pop(0)

    def append(self, carta):
        #   Agregar una carta (no validamos que este repetida)
        self.mano.append(carta)

    def remove(self, carta):
        self.mano.remove(carta)

    def __str__(self):
        return ' '.join(carta for carta in self.mano)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.mano)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.mano[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.mano[key] = value

#   Una baraja es una Mano con todas las cartas
baraja = Mano()
for palo in "DPCT":
    for numero in range(1, 13):
        baraja.append(f"{palo}{numero}")
random.shuffle(baraja)
print(f"Baraja: {baraja}")

#   La mesa también es una colección de cartas
mesa = Mano()

# Repartamos cinco cartas al jugador 1
player1 = Mano()
for i in range(5):
    player1.append(baraja.extraer()) #   Sacamos la primera carta de la baraja

print(f"Baraja : {baraja}")
print(f"Player1: {player1}")

#   Player1 selecciona una carta al azar y la juega
carta = input("Selecciona su carta: ").upper()
player1.remove(carta)
mesa.append(carta)

print(f"Player1: {player1}")
print(f"Mesa:: {mesa}")

produce:
Baraja: C9 D12 P4 P8 P12 D5 T7 P2 C8 C4 C7 D10 P5 T1 T11 P7 C12 P11 D11 C10 C3 T10 T9 T12 P6 P3 C11 D7 C1 D9 D6 T5 T4 D2 D1 T3 P9 P10 D4 P1 C6 C5 D3 T6 T8 T2 D8 C2
Baraja : D5 T7 P2 C8 C4 C7 D10 P5 T1 T11 P7 C12 P11 D11 C10 C3 T10 T9 T12 P6 P3 C11 D7 C1 D9 D6 T5 T4 D2 D1 T3 P9 P10 D4 P1 C6 C5 D3 T6 T8 T2 D8 C2
Player1: C9 D12 P4 P8 P12
Selecciona su carta: D12
Player1: C9 P4 P8 P12
Mesa:: D12

Process finished with exit code 0

